# Cisco router date time via SNMPv2

Tags: snmp, cisco

Im trying to get internal cisco router date time via SNMP.

CLI analog of what I want to get is "show clock".

Is there any specific OID to get this information via SNMP (besides the upTime OID which are not helpful in this case)?

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the OID you're looking for is:

1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.131.1.1.1 - csyClockDateAndTime

From the Description: "The current local date and time for the system."

It's a read-write object (read-only on some systems).

Pls refer to http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.131.1.1.1.

Comment: This is not available on my router, but thanks for the information.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe you can use snmpwalk to traverse the whole tree and see what is available for you in that router? Good luck, and thanks for the upvote.